# Maximum difference between two elements is equal to solve Maximum Subarray?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

In one book (Introduction to Algorithm, but I don't remember which chapter) I learned that to solve Maximum difference between two elements  problem:

> Maximum difference between two elements such that larger element
>   appears after the smaller number.
>
> Examples: If array is [2, 3, 10, 6, 4, 8, 1] then returned value
>   should be 8 (Diff between 10 and 2). If array is [ 7, 9, 5, 6, 3, 2 ]
>   then returned value should be 2 (Diff between 7 and 9)

is equal to solve the maximum subarray problem:

> Find the contiguous subarray within an array (containing at least one
>   number) which has the largest sum.
>
> For example, given the array [−2,1,−3,4,−1,2,1,−5,4], the contiguous
>   subarray [4,−1,2,1] has the largest sum = 6.

In order to solve *Maximum difference between two elements problem* for
`[2,3,10,6,4,8,1]`, it can be convert to a *max subarray problem* for array:

`[1,7,-4,-2,4,-7]` where 1 is difference between 2,3; 7 is difference between 3,10; etc.

I am wondering why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume that the maximum difference in array `A` is between elements `A[i]` and `A[j]` and is equal to `diff`.

```
diff = A[j] - A[i]           (j > i)
```

Lets also assume that between `A[i]` and `[j]` there are `N` elements.
You can also get the value `diff` by:

```
diff = (A[j]-A[j-1]) + (A[j-1]-A[j-2]) + ... + (A[i+2]-A[i+1]) + (A[i+1]-A[i])
```

As you might already see, each `(A[*]-A[*-1])` represents an element in the differences array. Meaning that the subarray with the largest sum is equal to the maximum difference between every two elements.

**In general:**
Lets define `B` to be the difference array of `A`.
For each two elements `A[i]`, `A[j]` when `j>i`:

```
A[j]-A[i]  =  B[i] + ... + B[j-1]  =  sum(B[k]) 
                                      for k=i to j-1
```